# How should i solve this task?

Tags: c++

I got the homework,i try to solve it,but i dont know why its bad.
One of part of this code was a default:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*##SOLUTION##*/

/*##SOLUTION##*/

int main()
{
    Valami var;
    int i=var.ujszam();
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cin>>i;
    var.tarol(i);
    var.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I have to to supplement this code with some criterion.
I have to create **Valami** class after that I have to create **ujszam** method which is get the integer number and give it back.
I have to create **tarol** method which is save the Integer number.
and finally i have to create **print** method which is display the saved number.
The input -2 and 72,the result gonna be -2 and "A szam : 72"
Here is my attempt:

```
class Valami
{
    public:int tarol;
    public:int ujszam()
        {
        int i;
        cin>>i;
        return i;
        }
    public:void tarol(int ertek)
        {
        tarol=ertek;
        }
    public:void print()
        {
        cout << "A szam : " <<tarol<< endl;
        }
};
```

I try to fix it some many ways,but idk what is the problem.

Comment: neither do we know what is the problem. Please explain what the code is supposed to do and how it fails to accomplish that. Include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: I try it but my english is not a best unfortunately.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tarol` is used as name of both a variable and a function. You have to give another name to one of them.

example:

```
class Valami
{
    public:int tarol_var; // rename the variable
    public:int ujszam()
        {
        int i;
        cin>>i;
        return i;
        }
    public:void tarol(int ertek)
        {
        tarol_var=ertek; // rename the variable
        }
    public:void print()
        {
        cout << "A szam : " <<tarol_var<< endl; // rename the variable
        }
};
```